# Vaadin doesnt generate html due Security Config

Tags: spring-security, configuration, vaadin, http-status-code-401

Currently, I am learning Spring Security and I created this configuration file. 
Somehow, Vaadin generated HTML elements are blocked due `401 forbitten` requests. Does someone know how to allow Vaadin to generate views to allowed pages. For example, `"/login"` is permitAll() and should be generated without any issues, but for `"/"` route, user should be authenticated();

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL = "/login";
    private static final String LOGIN_FAILURE_URL = "/login?error";

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/VAADIN/**", "/PUSH/**", "/UIDL/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/vaadinServlet/UIDL/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/vaadinServlet/HEARTBEAT/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/secured").authenticated();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN");
                    auth.anyRequest().authenticated(); // Commenting this also doesnt help
                })
                .formLogin(loginForm -> {
                    loginForm.loginPage(LOGIN_URL);
                    loginForm.loginProcessingUrl(LOGIN_PROCESSING_URL);
                    loginForm.failureUrl(LOGIN_FAILURE_URL);
                })
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl(LOGOUT_SUCCESS_URL))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .rememberMe().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring()
                .requestMatchers("/resources/**")
                .requestMatchers("/VAADIN/**")
                .requestMatchers("/PUSH/**")
                .requestMatchers("/UIDL/**")
                .requestMatchers("/dev-bundle/**")
                .requestMatchers("/vaadinServlet/**")
                .requestMatchers("/chromewebdata/**")
                .requestMatchers("/images/**")
                .requestMatchers("/icons/**");
    }


    // Rest of beans...
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Please add answers for `SpringBoot 6` or above. Huge thanks

Comment: Have you tried ramping up the logging (especially for `org.springframework.securty`) to see where it fails?

Answer (score 2):

Vaadin provides a helper class for spring security configuration.
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/security/enabling-security/#security-configuration-class

If you won't/can't use it, take a look at the the configuration applied in VaadinWebSecurity class

Comment: Yes I know about `VaadinWebSecurity.class`, but I want to add my own security using spring security not vaadin's one. Maybe someone already did this succesfully